# Perform For-loop and show output which meets a certain criterion

Tags: core-language, iterators

I am new to *Mathematica* and I have a For loop like so:

```
For[i = 0, i < 15, i++, PowerMod[i, -1, 15]]
```

Currently it doesn't output anything. The calculation I am performing is i^-1 mod n. I want t his loop to output the values of i ONLY where i = i^-1 mod n. How can i accomplish this?

#### Edit

I can print the output by wrapping PowerMod in Print[]. How can I accomplish printing i and then the result from PowerMod? Here is what I tried, but it is incorrect since I don't know the syntax to use here:

```
For[i = 0, i < 15, i++, Print[i] Print[PowerMod[i, -1, 15]]]
```

This prints i and then the result of PowerMod below it. How can I get them on the same line?

Comment: Note that in _Mathematica_ For-loops always return `Null`, which does not print at top-level.

Comment: I edited my questions if you could take a look again please.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out looking at wolframs docs. Any clue if there is an equal sign with a ? above it symbol in mathematica?

Comment: Try `Overscript["=", "?"]`

Comment: Did I match your needs with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid the For-loop. Here is way to do this with functional programming tools, which are more idiomatic to *Mathematica*.

```
Quiet[Table[{i, PowerMod[i, -1, 15]}, {i, 1, 14}]] // Cases[{x_, x_} :> x]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 11, 14}
> ```

Comment: Nice use of the operator form of `Cases`, I never know when to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rephrase your question a little:

> I want this loop to, IFF $i\equiv i^{-1}\mod n$, output the value of $i$.

Translating this into Mathematica:

```
If[i == PowerMod[i, -1, n], Print[i]]
```

We can make a few improvements.  First, I'll use `Do` instead of `For` (Try to [avoid constructs like `For` and `While`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/21750) in Mathematica, they're less idiomatic).  I'll also make your loop a function, so you can easily call it for different moduli:

```
selfInverses[n_] := Do[If[i == PowerMod[i, -1, n], Print[i]], {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

We're still getting those "not invertible" errors, so let's try a slightly different tack.  By multiplying both sides of the condition by $i$, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
i(i)&\equiv i^{-1}(i)\mod n \\
i^2&\equiv 1\mod n
\end{align}
$$

Since you can always multiply two numbers [citation needed], you don't get those errors.  Putting in these changes:

```
selfInverses[n_] := Do[If[1 == PowerMod[i, 2, n], Print[i]], {i, n}]
```

(If for some reason you needed to keep `PowerMod[i, -1, n]`, I suggest checking that `i` is invertible first with `Not[CoprimeQ[i, n]] && PowerMod[i, -1, n] == i`)

Note that the iterator for this `Do`, `{i, n}`, loops from `1` to `n`, not `0` to `n - 1` as your code did.  However, since $0^2\equiv 0\not\equiv 1$ and $n^2\equiv n\equiv 0\not\equiv 1\mod n$, neither end case will change our results.

`Print`ing the results is less helpful if you want to use the results later, so we'll have the function generate a list instead:

```
selfInverses[n_] := 
 Reap[Do[If[1 == PowerMod[i, 2, n], Sow[i]], {i, n}]][[2, 1]]
```

An example of usage:

```
selfInverses[15] (* returns {1, 4, 11, 14} *)
```

If you're having trouble understanding what this function is doing, [look at the documentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18606/21750) of the functions used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function, which lets you calculate your result for any modulus `n`:

```
pm[n_Integer/;n>1]:=Quiet@Select[Range[0,n-1],PowerMod[#,-1,n]==#&]
```

e.g.:

```
pm[15]   (* {1,4,11,14} *)
pm[30]   (* {1,11,19,29} *)
pm[3129] (* {1,148,895,1042,2087,2234,2981,3128} *)
```